# Changing H4 font colour in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to change the colour of the font which appears in images in gallery pages such as this page on the [site](https://www.petrabishai.co.uk/collections/dune/).
I would like to change the text below each image (such a Trail Necklace 111) from `#666666` to `#007faa`.
I used the web inspector to identify that this is an H4 tag in a div class called portfoliotitle_3
It is also a link so altogether I've updated the following parts of the CSS, saved the CSS and refreshed the page a few times but the text colour doesn't change.

```css
#contentwide .portfoliotitle h4 {
  color: #007faa;
}

.portfoliotitle a,
.portfoliotitle a:visited {
  color: #007faa;
}

#contentwide .portfoliotitle_3 h4 {
  color: #007faa;
}

.portfoliotitle_3 a,
.portfoliotitle_3 a:visited {
  color: #007faa !important;
}

.portfoliotitle_3 a:hover {
  color: #007faa;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

I must be missing something very basic and if anyone can take a fresh look and give me some pointers, that would be very appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Well, its changes for me. You got a cache problem maybe.

Comment: Many thanks SMAKSS and all for your replies. Yes, turns out it must have been a cache problem. I had tried clearing it in Firefox earlier but that hadn't been enough, so I refreshed elsewhere and tried other browsers and hey presto, the blue colour is there!

Answer (score 0):

i think Thats because the page load style.css of the page after each reload

Answer (score 0):

It's because of an `anchor` tag that has some important in color.. so you should probably change the anchor tag to change the color.

```
.portfoliotitle_3 a, .portfoliotitle_3 a:visited {
  color:#007faa !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cascading is apply for the element a. You can delete this code in internal css style element.

```
.portfoliotitle_3 a, .portfoliotitle_3 a:visited {
    color: rgb(85, 212, 255) !important;
}
```